# Computer got stuck on infinite loop in a programme

Tags: 20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04. When there is an infinite loop in my c++ code computer is becoming stuck.What is the solution?

Comment: We don't know your code.

Comment: actually like while(1){} will make computer stuck and i have to restart it again .

Comment: you can kill your program. Say your program was called `infinite`, then in another terminal run `killall infinite` .

Comment: But i heard from my friends that computer should automatically terminate it. Is there any way. Because i am unable to open terminal when it become stuck.

Comment: If it's running in the shell foreground, you can try suspending it (Ctrl+Z) then killing it via the PID or %jobspec

Comment: Computers are not magic nor can the read minds the program is doing what you told it to do.

Comment: Infinite loop in your code definitely should not make the whole computer stuck. This would be the case long ago in DOS ;), that could run only one program at a time. Linux is (and always was) a **multiprocess** operating system (like all recent OS-es) which means many programs can run simultaneously. It's only your program that is stuck, but you can open another session and kill your program. (cont.)

Comment: You say you can't open terminal when your program is stuck - how did you try to open the terminal? In GUI, Ctrl+Alt+T or opening new window from the terminal window menu should work; if you're connected via ssh, just start a new ssh session. If you are at the physical text console of your computer, Alt+F1 through Alt+F6 keys should switch you to different terminals. There always should be a way. Please give us more details.